# Categories and Subcategories in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have setup categories in mysql with the same number of depths as in this article: http://sqllessons.com/categories.html

Everything works OK. The problem is that I only want to show categories that actually have some something in them (products)

Example of categories:

```
Table 'categories':

id, parent_id, name
--------------------
85140, 800000, subcat1
85150, 800000, subcat2
85160, 800000, subcat3 
85170, 800000, subcat4 
851710, 85170, subsubcat_of_subcat_4
```

I have another table with products matching the id's in the categories table

```
Table 'products':

product_id, id
---------------
1001, 85140
1002, 85140
1003, 85150
1004, 85170
1005, 851710
```

When running the first query from the article I get all categories but I do not want to include "85160" as it is empty. How do I modify the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM categories ca
JOIN products pd
ON ca.id = pd.id;
```